# Production TestFlight test crashes when start, but the same code/archive works when is signed for development distribution

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

please we need your help.

- We are using Xcode 13.4.1 for compatibility with a library.
- We have a published app on March 1st of this year with any problem.
- On August 31 we have uploaded a new version for test purposes, it was distributed by TestFlight without any problem.
- Our original IOS distribution certificate expires on 2022/12/17.
- On September 15th, we have created a new IOS distribution certificate.
- On October 6th, we have create an App Store Profile based on the new iOS Distribution profile.

Our problem is when we archive new versions of the App and distribute for testing purposes by TestFlight, when we run on different devices (without iOS 16 by the way), it crashes. In devices with iOS 16, seems work fine.
We have tested with the same archive but signed and exported for development, the App installed using this IPA works without any issue.

We also have tried deploy the same code of the App with a new archive IPA of August 31, it also crashes; this make us suspect the problem is at the signing/distribution phase.

We have the same problem at all crash reports give the next information:

- Incident Identifier: ...
- Hardware Model:      iPhone13,4
- Process:             ... [10985]
- Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../....app/...
- Identifier:          ...
- Version:             2.0.23 (191)
- AppStoreTools:       14A305
- AppVariant:          1:iPhone13,4:15
- Beta:                YES
- Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
- Role:                Foreground
- Parent Process:      launchd [1]
- Coalition:           ... [1311]
- Date/Time:           2022-09-27 15:20:07.0591 -0500
- Launch Time:         2022-09-27 07:43:13.9385 -0500
- OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.6.1 (19G82)
- Release Type:        User
- Baseband Version:    2.70.01
- Report Version:      104
- Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
- Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
- Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
- Termination Reason: DYLD 4 Symbol missing
- Symbol not found: (_*swift_FORCE_LOAD*$_swiftFoundation)
- Referenced from: '/Volumes/VOLUME/*/....app/Frameworks/IBMMobileFoundationSwift.framework/IBMMobileFoundationSwift'
- Expected in: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation'
- (terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)

Triggered by Thread:  0
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x0000000100a40b14 __abort_with_payload + 8
1   dyld                            0x0000000100a466cc abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104 (terminate_with_reason.c:102)
2   dyld                            0x0000000100a46700 abort_with_payload + 16 (terminate_with_reason.c:124)
3   dyld                            0x0000000100a16a00 dyld4::halt(char const*) + 580 (DyldProcessConfig.cpp:2102)
4   dyld                            0x0000000100a13a20 dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 3560 (dyldMain.cpp:0)
5   dyld                            0x0000000100a11d84 start + 488 (dyldMain.cpp:864)
Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x0000000000000006   x1: 0x0000000000000004   x2: 0x000000016fd21868   x3: 0x0000000000000119
x4: 0x000000016fd21468   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x000000016fd20ee0
x8: 0x0000000000000020   x9: 0x0000000000000009  x10: 0x000000016fd2156b  x11: 0x000000000000013d
x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000031  x14: 0x0000000212138c02  x15: 0x000000016fd20a38
x16: 0x0000000000000209  x17: 0x0000000100a3b1c8  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
x20: 0x000000016fd21468  x21: 0x0000000000000119  x22: 0x000000016fd21868  x23: 0x0000000000000004
x24: 0x0000000000000006  x25: 0x000000016fd21468  x26: 0x0000000000000400  x27: 0x0000000000000400
x28: 0x0000000000000103   fp: 0x000000016fd21430   lr: 0x0000000100a466cc
sp: 0x000000016fd213f0   pc: 0x0000000100a40b14     cpsr: 0x1000
esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
0x1009f8000 - 0x100a4ffff dyld arm64e  <66e1fb2668f8379ba052eb8b8291b5e1> /usr/lib/dyld

We have tried automatically and manual signing without any change. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer at Apple Forums
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/715162?answerId=728753022#728753022

Extra configuration :

- Build Settings / deployment / oAlways Embed Swift Libraries = Yes
- Build Settings / deployment / strip swift symbol = No

Also when uploading :

- Unselect 2 first options about BitCode and Strip Swift Symbols

The solution worked with xCode 13.4.1 and some earlier versions.